# Loadbalancing between two isp uplinks

Tags: networking, router, firewall, load-balancing

We have currently at work two ISP boxes(routers), i want to setup a firewall to protect an intranet on a local host. The problem is that not every one is using the same router.

Here is my question: how can i do to make all traffic be sent to one location (firewall-loadbalancer) then the loadbalancer switchs automatically between the two routers .

EDIT:
The network is a small office network, there's 6 hosts and the intranet runs an one of them. The host must be reachable from outside but a firewall rule must filters the incoming connections. The rest of the network must send traffic to one locations, which forwards it automatically to the two routers.

EDIT2:
Here is the current diagram : http://goo.gl/RBRvS

Solution: I found that i have either to use a bond interface on the firewall as pberlijn sayed, or routing manually to each router like here [linux advanced routing](http://www.linuxhorizon.ro/iproute2.html)

Comment: possible duplicate of [2 WAN to LAN, What router do I need?](http://superuser.com/questions/275573/2-wan-to-lan-what-router-do-i-need)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Loadbalancing between two isp uplinks](http://serverfault.com/questions/270482/loadbalancing-between-two-isp-uplinks)